# Blurring a picture gradually based on amounts of clicks (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, button, blur

I want to blur a picture gradually depending on the number of clicks of the button 'Blur picture'. For example: if the user clicks one time it will blur the pic a little, then the second click will blur a little more, and so on...
Is there a library that does this, else how can I achieve it?

I would like to do this in React-Native but if you know how to do it using another language, I am opened to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image component has a property called "**blurRadius**" which you can trigger on touch (you'll have to use a touchable container like TouchableHighlight if the target is an Image).

Check the following example which does exactly what you describe; I use the state to keep track of the blur level.

https://snack.expo.io/@danyalejandro/b38413

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableHighlight, Image, View } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  state: {
    radius: number
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { radius: 0 };
  }


  _imagePressed() {
    this.setState({ radius: this.state.radius + 4 });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._imagePressed.bind(this)}>
          <Image
            blurRadius={this.state.radius}
            style={{ width: 320, height: 240 }}
            source={{
              uri:
                "https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg"
            }}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Amazing! How about using something else than a blur. For example something like puzzle effect so each click would add a piece of the puzzle on top of the picture?

Comment: There's a bunch of Components for image filtering and animation you could use, maybe there's something similar to puzzle animations.

Comment: Searched if I could find something like that but I could not

Comment: If you're particularly interested in a react native image puzzle animation, that sounds like a good StackOverflow question

Comment: if you dont mind please give it a thumbs up so more people can see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066236/puzzle-effect-on-top-of-a-picture-react-native