# Puzzle effect on top of a picture (React-Native)

Tags: image, react-native, styles

I want to have a puzzle effect on top of a picture and each piece of the puzzle to be able to add manually. For example: user has a button 'AddPuzzle' and when he clicks it will add a piece of a puzzle (let it be just blank puzzle) which would cover one part of the picture that is laying on the background. So for each click, there will be added one piece of the puzzle on top of that picture until it completely covers it.

Is there any libraries that can do this? I searched but couldn't really find any. Or is there a way to do it manually?